# how to splite two dates between week in mysql month wise

Tags: mysql

I want to display  number of row in MySQL according number of week.
Suppose we pass jan startdate 2017-1-1 and endDate 2017-1-31 then totdal days is 31. We have to divide by 7 then it will 4 week and 3 days so total 5 week so I have to display like this

for jan

```
WeekRow
1
2
3
4
5
```

for Feb

```
WeekRow
1
2
3
4
```

I am trying to apply a query, but I am unable to do it.
I am facing this issue from long time, but still unable to fix.

Comment: would you like to do this using stored procedure then i can help you with this

Comment: yes i need Using Sp

Answer (score 0):

below code is working to get rid your problem.
i have wrote this code in hurry .....later on i ll optimize this ...
have a look..and let me know if you got any problem to understand it...

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_month_days_split`(in in_start_date datetime , in in_end_date datetime)
BEGIN

        declare temp_date datetime;
        declare temp_date_data int ;

        drop temporary table if exists temp_split;
        create temporary table  temp_split
        (
          number bigint not null
        );

        while(in_start_date <= in_end_date)
        do          
            set temp_date = (select date_add(in_start_date,interval 7 day));
            set temp_date_data = (select day(date_add(in_start_date,interval 6 day)));

            set @temp_last_number = (select number from temp_split order by number desc limit 1);

            if(temp_date_data % 7) =0
            Then 
                 insert into temp_split(number)
                 select (temp_date_data/7);



            else 
                  insert into temp_split(number)    
                  select @temp_last_number+1;   


            end if ;


            set in_start_date = temp_date ; 

        end while;

        select * from temp_split;
END
```

**call**

```
call sp_month_days_split('2017-12-01', '2017-12-31');
```